# EXTJS - Possible to have clickable hyperlinks in TextArea?

Tags: url, extjs, textarea

I am using EXTJS 3.2.1, and am wondering if the user inputs a URL such as www.stackoverflow.com into a TextArea and submits. Then when the page reloads, if I can display it as a clickable hyperlink?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a rich text editor (rtf), so yes.

The editor I am using to type this answer is a rich text editor. I can **format** the text, add links, etc.  The Rich Text Editor is a UI control that replaces a standard HTML textarea.

Comment: I am using an Ext.form.TextArea, not HTML.